# Papertrail versioning with correct numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, versioning

I have an article model that I want to track versions with, mainly so that users can see the history of a work in progress.

However, papertrail stores the first version of the article as a nil object.

What is the best way to keep the version numbers consistent and not have the nil object show up, because when that link is clicked on, obviously it's a nil object.

I know this is a simple question, but there doesn't seem to be a way, based on papertrail's documentation to turn on and off versioning for a specific object as opposed to a class.